# Count items in hierarchy of entities

Tags: ios, core-data, count, hierarchy

I have run into a problem, I did solve it but I feel that it is pretty inefficient, which involves traversing through a Core Data (for iOS) entity hierachy of parent/children references to count the amount of items attached to certain entities.

Let me be more specific. I have 2 types of entities: `Category` and `Attachment`.

The `Category` entities are linked via parent/children references. The attachments are linked to `Categories` as a many-to-one (many attachments to one category).

If I would like to count the amount of attachments that fall within the hierarchy of a given `Category`, is there a `NSFetchRequest` that I can do that is more efficient than this?

```c
NSInteger count = 0;

NSMutableArray *stack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[stack addObject:targetCategory];

while([stack count] > 0)
{
    Category *current = [stack lastObject];
    [stack removeLastObject];

    count += current.attachments.count;

    for (Category *cat in current.children)
    {
        [stack addObject:cat];
    }
}
```

`targetCategory` is the root Category chosen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(It is risky to answer with "that is not possible", but)* I am quite sure that there is no fetch request that fetches or counts objects recursively. You have to traverse the hierarchy, either with a recursive method or as you did.

Comment: Can it be done in SQL in a way? If so, is there a possibility to port that to a fetch request?

Comment: Or maybe there is another paradigm one can use to look at the data?

Comment: @dandrejvv: Directly accessing the SQLite store is dangerous, because the format is not officially documented and might change at any time.  You would have caching problems at well. Core Data is an object graph manager, not a database, so you should think of objects with relationships and not of database records. - I do not have an immediate idea how to solve your problem more efficiently. How many categories do you have? Is it really a performance problem to traverse the tree?

Comment: That's not what I meant. I don't want to go directly to the SQLite DB. I was wondering if there is a way that SQL queries can do this and if it is possible to port query in a way to the fetch request query. There are a couple of categories. It takes almost 2 seconds for the next screen to show up. Its sort of acceptable for now but I would like for it to be a bit more speedy if at all possible.

Comment: @dandrejvv: It might be possible with SQL (but I am not an SQL expert), but you cannot port arbitrary SQL queries to a fetch request, so this will not help. - I do not have a better idea at the moment.

Comment: I also tried the SUBQUERY function in the Predicate format string query but that will only take me 1 level deep. It really seems that multiple level hierarchy traversal can't be done in predicate format string queries. One will need to take a different avenue to get good performance. For myself, I'm going to leave my code as is. Until someone does give a better answer, I'm marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you need only to count objects, use `countForFetchRequest:error:` like the following:

```
NSError *err = nil;
NSUInteger count = [moc countForFetchRequest:request error:&err];
if(count == NSNotFound) {
  // Handle error
}
```

Obviously, @MartinR's advice remains valid.